# Yii2 Advanced Template: Adding stand-alone web pages

Tags: php, yii2

I added help.php under backend/views/site and I declare a function under SiteController.php to be able to recognize the link

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionHelp()
{
    return $this->render('help');
}
```

The link is now accessible but it gives me an error
Forbidden(#403) and it says "You are not allowed to perform this action."

Now, I would like to ask if how will I be able to view the web pages that I've created. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add content of `behaviors` method, in particular `AccessControl`.

Comment: what do you mean, sir @arogachev? You mean the code under behaviors function?

Comment: I mean find `public function behaviors()` in your controller and add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related with `AccessControl` filter.

You can add `help` action to the this list of allowed actions for example like this:

```
[
    'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'help'],
    'allow' => true,
],
```

You can read more and check how access rules are applied in according [documentation section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html).